# Toggle related element on link's click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 classes in my HTML document: `links` and `elements`. I want to toggle specific element when specific link is clicked.
I have tried this:

```
var links = $('.links');
var elements = $('.elements');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links.eq(i).click(function() {
        elements.eq(i).toggle();
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem is the closure variable in a loop.

But we can solve it using [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index) like

```
var links = $('.links');
var elements = $('.elements');

links.click(function () {
    elements.eq(links.index(this)).toggle();
    return false;
})
```

```js
var links = $('.links');
var elements = $('.elements');

links.click(function() {
  elements.eq(links.index(this)).toggle();
  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="links">1</a>
<a class="links">2</a>
<a class="links">3</a>
<a class="links">4</a>
<a class="links">5</a>
<div class="elements">1</div>
<div class="elements">2</div>
<div class="elements">3</div>
<div class="elements">4</div>
<div class="elements">5</div>
```

- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use a data attribute to reference the id of the element in question.

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="links" data-element-id="el-1">Links</a>
    <span class="elemennts" id="el-1">Elements</span>
</div>
<script>
$('.container').on("click", ".links", function() {
    $("#" + $(this).data("element-id")).toggle();
}
</script>
```